# Selecting data from SQL Server Using PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, xampp

I am trying to select data from a local database on my PC using PHP but i am getting this error when i run 127.0.0.1/test.php which is what the file is called.

error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php:11 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 11
```

Here is my PHP script:

```
  <?php
    $servername = "Windows local servername";
    $username = "Windows username";
    $password = "windows password";
$dbname = "dbname";

// Create connection
$conn = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn){
    die('error connecting to database');
}else{
    mysql_select_db(dbname, $conn);
}

$sql = "SELECT UserId, UserEmail, UserPassword FROM User";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["UserId"]. " - UserEmail: " . $row["UserEmail"]. " " . $row["UserPassword"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

I have looked around online but i cant figure out what is wrong here. I can run a hello world php script and it works so i am assuming its a connection issue with the database but what have i missed here? Thanks

**EXTRA:**

i have:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to run

```
phpinfo()
```

And look for the `mysql` extensions, in ubuntu you can install them by typing

```
sudo apt-get install php-pdo-mysql
```

Anyway the instruction you're trying to use was deprecated in HP 5.5.0 and deleted in PHP 7.0.0 so may be this is why its missing... depending on you PHP version, you could try with the `mysqli` extension instead like:

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
$res = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT 'Please, do not use ' AS _msg FROM DUAL");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
echo $row['_msg'];
```

You could get more info on the actual way of performing this with PHP7 at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php for instance

Comment: i am using php 7.2.8

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)

> This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP
>   7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

You'll probably want to use [Microsoft's drivers for PHP for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-driver-for-sql-server) rather than the ODBC driver in PDO.

Answer (score 0):

In place of 
$conn = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
use
$connectioninfo=array("Database"=>"dbname", "UID"=>"userid", "PWD"=>"password", );

$con = sqlsrv_connect($server,$connectioninfo);